# Chrome and Safari find localhost in two different locations

Tags: homebrew, apache, webserver, mamp

I've been trying to set up MAMP (macOS, Apache, MySQL, PHP) using Homebrew on macOS Monterey.

I set the file directory for Apache as `/Users/myname/Sites` in `httpd.conf`. When I go to http://localhost in Chrome, I get the `index.html` page in that directory. But when I go to http://localhost in Safari, it opens the `index.html` page in `/Library/WebServer/Documents`.

Do I somehow have 2 copies of Apache running? How do I resolve this conflict?

Comment: Can you check with the terminal command `sudo lsof -i | grep LISTEN` what processes are listening? Also, can you check your `/etc/hosts` file? [It appears that Safari (and Firefox)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/259721/24324) need both IPv4 and IPv6 specifications in that file. Perhaps that plays a role?

Comment: If you open `http://127.0.0.1` in Chrome and Safari, do you get the same page? If you open Terminal and run `curl http://localhost`, which `index.html` do you get?

Comment: Did you checked with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524826/localhost-not-working-in-chrome-127-0-0-1-does-work)